# Software & Updates missing from Applications dashboard

Tags: package-management, updates, software-center, gnome-dash

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and although both Ubuntu Software and Software Updater are present and working fine, Software & Updates is missing from Applications, and pressing the Settings button on the Updater asks for my password and then shows a busy cursor for a few seconds and then nothing. Running `software-properties-gtk` results in:

```
LSB codename: 'bionic'.
This codename isn't currently supported.
Please check your LSB information with "lsb_release -a".
```

Running `lsb_release -a` results in:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I have noticed a new app in the Application Menu called *Software Sources*. This program does the same thing as clicking the Settings button in Updater.

Comment: So, what was the result when you checked your LSB information? Please [edit] it into your answer.

Comment: Sorry, yes.... done

Comment: Ok, that's weird. Didn't expect that.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles over this question: I found an answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/1130933/704375. Essentially, your software-properties-gtk package has been overwritten by a version from the cinnamon ppa, which doesn't play nice with ubuntu codenames.