# Unable to install repositories during Wine installation: "This codename isn't currently supported."

Tags: 18.04, wine, repository

Update: "lsb_release -a" outputs:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

"apt-cache policy base-files" outputs:

```
base-files:
  Installed: 10.1ubuntu2.8
  Candidate: 10.1ubuntu2.8
  Version table:
 *** 10.1ubuntu2.8 500
        500 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     10.1ubuntu2.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     10.1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Update 2: grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list" output:

```
https://pastebin.com/gvha9kZT
```

Update 3:  apt-cache policy software-properties-common output:

```
https://pastebin.com/gEEjDP5Y
```

which add-apt-repository output:

```
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository
```

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, and as the title suggests I'm trying to install Wine version 5.0. Because my computer would not automatically update Wine from version 4.0, I began following instructions as laid out here: [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)

To begin, I made sure to remove all Wine-related stuff with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --autoremove wine-*
```

I then followed N0rbert's instructions:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
```

He then notes that one should remove the WineHQ repository to avoid a mess with this command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

I'm already confident that I removed everything Wine related, so this command should only give me a response saying something along the lines that the repository couldn't be found or doesn't exist. However, I instead get this:

```
LSB codename: 'bionic'.
This codename isn't currently supported.
Please check your LSB information with "lsb_release -a".
```

This was weird and indicative of errors to come, but I proceed with the confidence that that repository doesn't exist and that I don't really need to worry too much about that step.

The problem really shows itself when I try to add a repository, in this case to install the "libfaudio0" package which is apparently missing and necessary to install Wine 5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 (as it's only readily available for 19.10 and up, making the installation process a little different on older versions). I follow these directions, up to adding the repository:

```
wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./'
sudo apt-get update
```

When I attempt to add the repository, I again get the message from earlier stating "This codename isn't currently supported." So far I have not found a solution for this.

I tried to fix it by copying the solution posted here: [fingerprint-gui in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112912/fingerprint-gui-in-18-04/1130933#1130933) . Essentially, he claims that with Cinnamon (which I think I downloaded), one also inadvertently installs MintSources, which is for Linux Mint and causes problems when running commands that depend on "software-properties-common," "software-properties-gtk," and "python3-software-properties." However this did not resolve my problem either, as I am still getting the message about the codename.

How do I go about fixing this? I have not found much at all online referring to this codename message. If you need more information from my system, just tell me what I need to put in the terminal so I may relay that information back to you.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Please also add output of `lsb_release -a` and `apt-cache policy base-files` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert The outputs of these commands have been added to the beginning of my post

Comment: It is still hard to find real reason of the problem. Please also add output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list" and `dpkg -l | grep wine`` to the question body. If output is long - use PasteBin.com.

Comment: @N0rbert I was able to run `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` but couldn't get `dpkg -l | grep wine``` to do anything. Here is the pastebin for the former, which I've added to the post: https://pastebin.com/gvha9kZT

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy software-properties-common` with `which add-apt-repository` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert I've added the output for the first command to the post, here's the link https://pastebin.com/gEEjDP5Y . All I got from `which add-apt-repository` was /usr/bin/add-apt-repository , but I'll add that as well

Comment: Do you really need the Cinnamon PPA? Did you tried to install all upgrades to the system by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ?

Comment: I do not think I need Cinnamon - at the moment I'm unsure if I'm actually using it in any way. I just installed updates automatically queued by my system in addition to running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. I will restart my computer and see if there is any difference when adding repositories

Comment: To be clear, I'm unsure if Cinnamon has anything to do with my problem. Anyways, after installing upgrades and restarting I am still getting the 'codename' message when attempting to add or remove repositories (as I just attempted according to your guide to install Wine in the other question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106481/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-plopperizer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During chat session we have discovered that `software-properties-common` package was not upgraded to last version, it had installation candidate from Cinnamon PPA.
So we have removed this PPA and reinstalled this package by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:trebelnik-stefina/cinnamon

sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-properties-common
```

then remove Wine repository by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main"
```

Then finally followed my method [from other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1205596/66509):

```
wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./'

sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key; sudo apt-key add winehq.key

sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

Add PPA for the required `libfaudio0` you can purge it later.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
```

Now install:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

*Alternatively*

If you get dependencies issues try:

```
sudo apt install libgnutls30:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libxml2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386
```

[Source](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/Wine-Dependencies)

Comment: The first two commands worked fine, though I got a message stating `File 'winehq.key' already there; not retrieving.` which I suppose either wasn't deleted or I added again recently trying to get this to work and forgot about. However, I could not add the two repositories, as for both the WineHQ one and the libfaudio0 one I got the same codename message as before.

Comment: Here's [Another tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/wine-5-release/), much likely the same, make sure to follow each step.

Comment: I actually tried following that tutorial before finding N0rbert's post. However, whenever I get to the part where I need to add a repository I get a message stating `LSB codename: 'bionic'. This codename isn't currently supported. Please check your LSB information with "lsb_relases -a".` I'm following the instructions exactly, but my system is just not able to add repositories, preventing me from completing the process of installation. I think my issue has more to do with this inability to add repositories than installing Wine in general, but I appreciate your comments.