# unable to add any repository via add-apt

Tags: apt, 18.04, repository

I have same computer, installed from same image as my college, but yet I'm not able to add new repositories to ubuntu. I'm not aware of any relevatn modifications made to the system, and I'd really like to avoid reinstall. Is there any way how to add new apt repositories to 18.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily
LSB codename: 'bionic'.
This codename isn't currently supported.
Please check your LSB information with "lsb_release -a".

mmucha@utu:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

if I add that repository manually, there is missing GPGkey or invalid, but I have no idea how to download GPG for ppa... Details of failing GPG here:
[fingerprint-gui in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112912/fingerprint-gui-in-18-04)

maybe related question: [Software & Updates missing from Applications dashboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097745/software-updates-missing-from-applications-dashboard/1110782)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the PPA manually. Create a file in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory called freecad.list.

Note you can really name the file whatever you like but it needs to be in that directory and it needs to have a .list extension. Put this in the file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily/ubuntu bionic main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily/ubuntu bionic main
```

Comment: I'm ubuntu newbie, but sure, I tried to do that. Details are in that fingerprint-gui link: In that case I will get PGP error. But it's really weird, that add-apt does not work: I have supported distribution and it's rejected. And I don't know how to resolve in secure manner that GPG error. Copy-pasted here: W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EFD5FA852F20733F

Comment: Try manually adding the key too: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2F20733F  (note that 2F20733F is the last 8 characters of the full key ID in the error message)

Comment: Can you explain to me, what it does first? I understood it, that this just adds this GPG key among trusted ones and that's it. If that would be the case, and someone would be playing tricks on me, I'd just open the door for the man-in-the-middle. But I don't understand this sufficiently, so can you please explain the command( I tried to understand it myself but I'm still unsure) and tell me if it's actually safe to do this? Thanks!

Comment: There are four fields in the `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily/ubuntu bionic main` software source 1. type 2. URI 3. distribution 4. components. type of source is `deb` (.deb file) URI is `http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily/ubuntu`, distribution is `bionic` (18.04) components is `main` Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: @EricMintz OK, I'm not sure what exactly apt-key does, but lets hope it contacts given keyserver and asks public keys of given hash to be downloaded. I did that, and then by-hand added repository source works and I can install from it. THanks.

Comment: I've added an answer to one of your other posts, which has the same error. Check it here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1130933/941020 If this solves your issue, please mark this as a duplicate :)